# Make TextMate run php from a different binary, not the original php

Tags: textmate, php

I work with php and postgre, and since the stock php doesn't come with postgre I had to install a different php version.

So I installed php5 from this website: http://php-osx.liip.ch

It's a quick install, just downloaded php5 and its modules and put them in a different directory, now everything works, except the TextMate's "php run".

I couldn't find where TextMate makes the call to the php and I wanna change it, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting PATH in TextMate > Preferences > Variables to `<path to php5>:$PATH` or similar (important is that the path to php5 is listed first), for example `/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`?

Answer (score 4):

Under preferences, go into variables and update (or create) `TM_PHP` to point to your desired executable. E.g. I have `/opt/local/bin/php` because I'm using MacPorts.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was /usr/local/php5/bin/php whereas 'php5' is an alias that points to the liip installation dir /usr/local/php5-5.3.29-20141019-211753.
And by the way it solved my textmate line output on syntax checking on osx 10.12. Thanks a lot.